# Compress Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little situation here and in-spite of searching a lot - am not getting to a solution.

I am loading Javascript Files in the footer of my page as below

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/jScrollPane.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/common.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/preload.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/scroller.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/easing.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/jquery.backgroundPosition.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

All I want to do is instead of including the above files - just include one compressed file which is made by compressing all the above files.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/one.js'></script>
```

I have tried a lot of options and each time there is an error in the file generated.

Is there a solution where I upload all files - get one compressed file and it works without an error?

Is is possible that these files themselves are missing ending ;'s - the reason why there are errors?

What can I do to come to an alternative here.

Cheers!

Comment: What tool did you use to compress your files? It is quite likely that the error is for a reason any compressor will produce the same message. What was the error message?

Comment: Hello Andrew - I use a lot many online compilers - each one giving errors - so seems like I need to clean up my scripts first. Let me try out the alternatives and get back. The error messages were about functions and ;'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Paste each file into the [Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). Keep the optimization level at "Simple".
2. Correct any error you might get. Watch out for missing semicolons at the end of the file, as these do not trigger an error.
3. Concatenate the results in one file.

Done.

Comment: this seems like a good logical suggestion - starting to try this - let me get back...

Answer (score 3):

I would start of by running my code through JSLint http://www.jslint.com/ for instance, so that you can identify and solve any JS-errors.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like Minify: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

> Minify is a PHP5 app that helps you follow several of Yahoo!'s [Rules
>   for High Performance Web Sites](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/index.html#rules).
>
> It combines multiple CSS or Javascript files, removes unnecessary
>   whitespace and comments, and serves them with gzip encoding and
>   optimal client-side cache headers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a solution where I upload all files - get one compressed file and it works without an error?

Yes, assuming that your files are setup correctly.

> Is is possible that these files themselves are missing ending ;'s - the reason why there are errors?

Exactly, the files you minify must support the removing of line breaks. Missing semicolons are the biggest problem.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out the line and char of the error(s). If the error originates near the beginning or ending of a library, odds are that the issue is the semicolon. You can fix by adding a semicolon to the beginning of every library, or at least the ones before and after the error. Extra semicolons shouldn't cause probs.